# Получить динамический элемент jQuery (без события)

Tags: jquery

Получить любой элемент в jQuery можно так:

```
var element = $('#myElement');
```

Нужно, так же, получить элемент вставленный динамически. Без события на нем!

Событие (клик) происходит на одном (не динамическом) элементе. Но при этом событии нужно взять данные из другого (динамического, уже вставленного в страницу) элемента.

Comment: Вы пробовали сделать то, что описали, способом, который описали?

Comment: Да. В Хроме и опере работает. IE 11 и Firefox нет.

Comment: не хотите показать код и разметку?

Comment: @Deniel так конкретно вопрос и задавайте по IE

Answer (score 1):

Да, `.on("click","...",function(){...` сработает, но если на странице подключен *jQuery* версии с 1.7 и выше.

```
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

А если мы пишем поддерживаемый код со старой версией *jQuery*, то используем следующую конструкцию:

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
```

где селектор — это тот элемент, который есть или появится на странице динамически.
параметр `data` не обязателен

достаточно указать так:

```
$(".btn").live("click", function(){/*операции при клике на кнопку с классом .btn */});
```

Answer (score 0):

клик на созданного динамического элемента попробуй так.

$(document).on('click','класс или id динамический созданного элемента',function(){
        и здесь уже что захотите))

})